# 2D table of list of numbers and returns a list of 2 numbers indicating the position of the maximal element in the table

Tags: python, list, 2d

The function takes a single argument that is a 2D table of numbers (a list of number lists) and returns a list of 2 numbers indicating the position of the maximal element in the table. For example, of the maximal element is table[2][0], the function returns the list [2, 0]. Below are a couple of test executions below:

[image: Example of output]

So far I have,

```
def maxPos2D(table):
   l = []
   for i in range(len(table)):
      for j in i:
         if i > table:
            continue
            table[i][j] += 0
   return l
```

Comment: I don't quite undertand your example. Can you give a real functional valid input to your function and an exact valid output?

Comment: Explain what is not working in your code right now as well. Also, it would help if you fixed your own indentation to make sure the code is an exact representation of your own code int he editor

Comment: I have a screenshot of what the function is supposed to do. I'm supposed to identify the index at where the largest number is in a list of lists. So, I'm trying to find the row and column of the index. If the largest number in the list of lists was 60 and it was in the first list last number, my function should return [0,2]. I'm just very confused and really don't even know where to begin.

Comment: What should happen if there are two (or more) positions with the same maximumal value?

Comment: I'd assume that it would give the first position in the loop. Then you would also need an else statement

Answer (score 1):

You may use [`itertools.chain()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) as:

```
from itertools import chain

def maxPos2D(table):
    chained_list = list(chain(*table))  # create single list from table
    max_val = max(chained_list)  # find max value in list
    max_index = chained_list.index(max_val)  # find index of max value
    columns = len(table[0])  # number of columns
    return [max_index/columns, max_index%columns]  # return [column, row]
```

In case you do not want to import any module, you may create a function as:

```
def maxPos2D(table):
    max_index_parent, max_val = 0, max(table[0])  # initialise values based 
    max_index_child = table[0].index(max_val)     # on 1st sub-list
    for i, child in enumerate(table[1:], 1):
        max_child_val = max(child)
        if max_child_val > max_val:  # update values based on each sub-list
            max_index_parent, max_val = i, max_child_val
            max_index_child = child.index(max_val)
    return [max_index_parent, max_index_child]
```

---

Here is inefficient version of the program with `O(n^2)` complexity, considering it might be easier for OP to understand. *Not a suggested approach to do it*:

```
def maxPos2D(table):
    max_index_parent, max_index_child, max_val = None, None, None
    for i, child in enumerate(table):
        for j, val in enumerate(child):
            if max_val is None or val > max_val:
                max_index_parent, max_index_child, max_val = i, j, val
    return [max_index_parent, max_index_child]
```

Sample run:

```
>>> maxPos2D([[1, 2, 4], [7, 8, 9], [4, 5, 6]])
[1, 2]
```

Comment: I would remove the second solution. Why show a O(n^2) solution as a simpler version? It's less efficient. Just stick with the first solution.

Comment: @idjaw: Even though it is less efficient but considering the skill-set of user I think he will find it easier to understand instead of first solution.

Comment: I disagree with showing an inefficient solution without the appropriate explanation. Or at least explain that it is inefficient and the first one is more efficient. Make your answers more clear and indicate exactly why you are showing it with the appropriate disclaimer. You are not *just* doing this for this particular OP, but realize that there are several other users who will probably read this as well and it is important to put some thought in to how you answer for the next set of readers.

Comment: @idjaw: I agree you on that. Update the answer with disclaimer. Also added 1 more approach, little more effiecient one for other might be referring in the future

Answer (score 0):

Search through the table and record the only the highest values you find

```
In [1]: x = [[5,3,4,22,1], [1,1,1,1,1], [4,4,4,4,4], [3,3,3,3,3]]

In [2]: best_so_far = -999

In [3]: for i in range(len(x)):
   ...:     for j in range(len(x[i])):
   ...:         if x[i][j] > best_so_far:
   ...:             best_cords = [i,j]
   ...:             best_so_far = x[i][j]
   ...:             

In [4]: best_so_far
Out[4]: 22

In [5]: best_cords
Out[5]: [0, 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it might be best to break the processing into two separate functions, each one handling a different dimension of the 2D table. That way each only has a single purpose, which makes them each relatively easy to understand.

```
def maxRowElement(row):
    max_col_index, max_col_val = 0, row[0]

    for i, val in ((i, val) for i, val in enumerate(row) if val > max_col_val):
        max_col_index, max_col_val = i, val

    return max_col_index, max_col_val

def maxPos2D(table):
    max_row_index, max_col_index, max_tbl_val = 0, 0, table[0][0]

    for row_index, row in enumerate(table):
        col_index, col_val = maxRowElement(row)
        if col_val > max_tbl_val:
            max_col_index, max_tbl_val = col_index, col_val
            max_row_index = row_index

    return [max_row_index, max_col_index]


print(maxPos2D([[1]]))       # -> [0, 0]
print(maxPos2D([[1,2]]))     # -> [0, 1]
print(maxPos2D([[1,2],
                [3,0]]))     # -> [1, 0]
print(maxPos2D([[1,2,3],
                [10,20,15],
                [4,5,6]]))   # -> [1, 1]
print(maxPos2D([[1,2,3],
                [10,20,15],
                [4,5,60]]))  # -> [2, 2]
```